# How can I check authentication in ajax url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-visualization

Consider the following ajax call:

```
  function drawCharts() {
  var jsonData1 = $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:****/*/*",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;
```

My index.html

```
<div id="chart_div" title='Speedo Information'></div>
```

I am making an api that converts json data to tabular form using Google Visualization Api.

While accessing the url alone the url asks for a user name and password. I have the credentials.

**NOTE:** The username and password is used to protect the data in the url from unauthorized access.

I need to ask for a user name while opening the index.html page and then display the table.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has an Ajax interface pretty well described here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There basic example looks like this with your URL in there. It shows how to override the MIME type and how to get a function called once the request returns data from the server. The API also offers an error function and many other features to transform the request in various ways.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:*/*/*",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
.done(function( data ) {
  if ( console && console.log ) {
    console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
  }
});
```

If you want to send the login and password or any other data to the server, you may also use the `data: ...` field. That can hold data as in a POST from a form.

Comment: I have used jolokia and converted my jmx to jason format which is stored in this url. `http://localhost:****/*/*` . And to access this url I have a username and password. I need to pass this url in ajax url form.

Comment: Will try this and get back to you.