# Authorize request before JqGrid delete confirmation box

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using JqGrid in my MVC application and using the delOptions for delete functionality.

Now I have written an attribute to check authorization over the delete action, but before checking the authorization it is showing the delete confirmation popup.

So, I want to do an ajax call before delete confirmation box to check authorization over delete action.

How could I do that?

Below is the code :

```
'delOptions: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                    mtype: "POST",
                                   },
                cancel: false,
                save: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete")'
            }' 

$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
        caption: "Delete",
        width: 360,
        msg: paramFromView.DeleteAllConfirmationMessage,
        bSubmit: "Delete",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        processData: "Processing..."
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.

U should run an [AJAX call for checking authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541825/how-can-i-check-authentication-in-ajax-url).

Then if the user is authenticated, then u should proceed your normal work, otherwise, restrict the user.

---

If u want more specific answer, please update your question being more specific with code.

Comment: Below is the code :  'delOptions: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Delete")',
                    mtype: "POST",
                                   },
                cancel: false,
                save: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete")'
            }'  '$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
        caption: "Delete",
        width: 360,
        msg: paramFromView.DeleteAllConfirmationMessage,
        bSubmit: "Delete",
        bCancel: "Cancel",
        processData: "Processing..."
    });'

Comment: Please update your question so that it can be readable and so I can help. And if u find my answer acceptable, please click on tick mark which will give u and me some points